# How to handle user authentication in laravel when backend and frontend are split in two git repos and domains

Tags: laravel, authentication, architecture, frontend, backend

I'am working on a larger web app using laravel (v8) because of the expected size to which the project probably will grow I decided to split the frontend and backend into two different repos from the beginning.

Now I want to implement user authentication for the frontend my problem now is how should I approach this. I would know where to start when frontend and backend would be in the same repo but split like this I can't seem to find a way to wrap my head around it.

FYI: I already implemented token based authentication for my backend routes

EDIT: Adjusted title

Answer (score 1):

It's is very simple you can authenticate to an endpoint, let's call it /api/login, this endpoint will return the token, the refresh_token and the user as json format, then just save the token into local storage via javascript or in another place (cookies, localfile, etc), then when you make an api call just use the saved token to pass the laravel api middleware, check this login example code using Laravel Passport and Laravel Responder packages

```
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();//array valid data
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    try {
        $response = $this->client->post("{$this->oauth_server}/oauth/token", [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('auth.oauth_client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('auth.oauth_secret'),
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ],
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return responder()->error($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage())->respond();
    }

    return responder()->success([
        "oauth" => json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true)
    ])->respond();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I got you to the point where I save the token in local storage, but then later how exactly would I pass the saved token to the laravel api middlewar?

Comment: Very simple, I suppose that you use a Baerer token, in the request you just add the header 
`Authorization: Baerer you_token_here`, and done

Comment: You should never store the refresh_token and access_token in your local-storage, as this storage is not safe. This is a bad-practise. Use Cookies to do authentication for you. Just make sure, you're managing CORS correctly and also mitigate CSRF attacks. With a refresh-token attackers can do so much more harm as with a auth-cookie. They can generate new access-tokens until the refresh-token expires (which is usually a long time)